# pexpect to login to custom shell

Tags: python, ssh, expect, spawn, pexpect

I have a custom shell which looks like below.

testuser:

How do I set custom PROMPT attribute to login to a shell which look like

I'm reusing the hive.py code from samples section and set original_prompt to :.

original_prompt='[:]'

The result is it skips the host as it fails to connect with

- ERROR could not synchronize with original prompt

What am I missing?

Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: I don't see anything named `original_prompt` in [the `hive.py` sample from the current `pexpect`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pexpect/pexpect/master/examples/hive.py). Can you show us actual sample code?

Comment: Also, why are you searching for `'[:]'`? That's a regular expression that matches any single character in the set consisting of nothing but `:`—in other words, it should match exactly the same things as `':'` would. So… are you trying to do something different?

Answer (score 0):

The prompt should be needed after having written a command and waiting for it to finish. You have to tell "readline" what it should expect (in your case "testuser:").